# Is there a way to find and replace all occurence of a string in mongoDB Collection?

Tags: mongodb, find-replace

I am having a document like this.

```
{
"_id" : "59a82381362a337f2b50afb2",
"title" : "First Page here",
"slug" : "first-page-here",
"header_image" : null,
"status" : "active",
"seo" : {
    "meta_title" : "First page",
    "meta_content" : "Firts page for Tareto",
    "meta_description" : "Tarento to have a first page"
},
"sections" : [
    {
        "title" : null,
        "position" : "0",
        "columns" : [
            {
                "column_size" : "12",
                "column_type" : "Text",
                "column_title" : null,
                "blocks" : {
                    "block_id" : "1",
                    "block_type" : "Text",
                    "block_title" : null,
                    "block_contents" : "First page test",
                    "block_image" : null,
                    "block_image_width" : null,
                    "block_image_height" : null,
                    "block_image_alt_text" : null,
                    "block_image_align" : null
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title" : null,
        "position" : "1",
        "columns" : [
            {
                "column_size" : "12",
                "column_type" : "Accordion",
                "column_title" : null,
                "blocks" : {
                    "block_id" : "2",
                    "block_type" : "Accordion",
                    "block_title" : null,
                    "block_contents" : null,
                    "block_image" : null,
                    "block_image_width" : null,
                    "block_image_height" : null,
                    "block_image_alt_text" : null,
                    "block_image_align" : null,
                    "block_child" : [
                        {
                            "title" : "Accordion section 1",
                            "description" : "First page test"
                        },
                        {
                            "title" : "Accordion Section 2 first page",
                            "description" : "First page"
                        },
                        {
                            "title" : "Accordion Section 3",
                            "description" : "first page"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"website_id" :"59a8227e362a337be32c6392"}
```

I would like to replace "first page" in the collection to "last page". The string which I am looking for can comes under any object.

I tried this query

```
db.pages.find({"_id":ObjectId("59a82381362a337f2b50afb2")}).forEach(function(url,k){ url.seo.meta_content=url.seo.meta_content.replace("Firts page for Tareto","First page for Tarento"); db.pages.save(url) });
```

The query update the meta content under seo.

I would like to do find and replace for the complete collection. Please help me on this.

Comment: What is the _field name_ you are trying to find-replace the values for?

Comment: For every field & for every doc in a collection then this is better be done at code rather than thru MongoDB's queries !!

Comment: @whoami thanks for your suggestion. I will try to implement the same.